# Assign multiple user to HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, hasura

[image]

This is hasura console environment variable screenshot,

Is it possible to assign `multiple user role` in hasura console?
right now its not working for me,

only public_user is working, its avoiding everything after space.
when I do query with admin_user role, I am getting error like `tablename` not found in `query_root`.

Also If I move `admin_user` before `public_user`, then `public_user` will stop working.

Or is there any other way we can have `2 unauthorized role` in hasura.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> You can use the env variable `HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE` or the `--unauthorized-role` flag to *set a role* for unauthenticated (non-logged in) users.

Only one role allowed.

If you want to make requests as admin user you need to pass the value of `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET` as a header.

```js
await fetch(`https://url.com/v1/graphql`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.strigify({}),
  headers: { "x-hasura-admin-secret": process.env.HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET },
});
```

> This is the simplest mode of authentication. Here's how authentication
> with an admin secret works:
>
> 1. Hasura is configured with an admin password on startup
> 2. When making an API request the client passes the admin password in the header
>    X-Hasura-Admin-Secret
> 3. Hasura validates the admin secret and allows access to all resources